# SendGrid domain authentication with Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, sendgrid

How do I authenticate my Heroku domain, https://my-app.herokuapp.com/, with SendGrid? I want to use the domain, because it's already secure. I haven't been able to find a DNS setting or a way to do it.

Thanks!